# how to validate a new web window opened in appium mobile automation

Tags: selenium, mobile, automation, appium

Since we do have only control over mobile app window,how we can validate a web browser window opened from a native android application,someone please help

Comment: You should search for questions on hybrid apps in Appium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to switch context to [webview](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/context/set-context/),

[how to use](https://medium.com/@kevinmarkvi/switching-to-a-dynamically-named-context-handle-with-appium-and-java-c78d2b972eb6)

Comment: Thanks for your help